# How to deconstruct a struct correctly?

Tags: solidity, struct

I have the following code:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.23;

contract Dummy {
    struct MyStruct {
        address[] a;
        uint256 b;
    }

    MyStruct public myStruct;

    constructor() {
        myStruct.a = new address[](1);
        myStruct.a[0] = address(0);
        myStruct.b = 1;
    }
}

contract Dummy2 {
    function myFunction() external {
        Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
        (address[] memory a, uint256 b) = dummy.myStruct();
    }
}
```

However, when I try to deconstruct `dummy.myStruct()` with `(address[] memory a, uint256 b) = dummy.myStruct();`, I get the following error:

```
Different number of components on the left hand side (2) than on the right hand side (1).solidity(7364)
Type uint256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type address[] memory.solidity(9574)
```

How should this be done correctly?

The following code compiles fine so I guess, the problem is related to the use of an array inside the struct?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.23;

contract Dummy {
    struct MyStruct {
        bool a;
        uint256 b;
    }

    MyStruct public myStruct;

    constructor() {
        myStruct.a = true;
        myStruct.b = 2;
    }
}

contract Dummy2 {
    function myFunction() external {
        Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
        (bool a, uint256 b) = dummy.myStruct();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `myStruct` function in the Dummy contract returns a `MyStruct` struct, not a `MyStruct` memory struct.

1. Add a getter function for the `myStruct` variable to the Dummy contract
2. In the Dummy2 contract, use the function to access the data in the storage

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

contract Dummy {
    struct MyStruct {
        address[] a;
        uint256 b;
    }

    MyStruct public myStruct;

    constructor() {
        myStruct.a = new address[](1);
        myStruct.a[0] = address(0);
        myStruct.b = 1;
    }

    function getMyStruct() external view returns (MyStruct memory) {
        return myStruct;
    }
}

contract Dummy2 {
    function myFunction() external {
    Dummy dummy = new Dummy();
    Dummy.MyStruct memory ds = dummy.getMyStruct();
    address[] memory a = ds.a;
    uint256 b = ds.b;
    }
}
```